# Plotly ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: pandas, plotly

I am trying to plot scatter plots from a pandas dataframe groupby object while trying to use values from a second dataframe of identical shape for error bars. Here is the code I used:

```
for key, group in results_new_mean_gal.groupby("Donor"):

    Y_error = results_new_CV_gal.groupby("Donor")

    group.iplot(subplots = True, subplot_titles = True, legend =False, x="Time", kind="scatter", mode="lines+markers", error_y=Y_error.get_group(key), error_type="data")
```

I am getting the following error:
Plotly ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I am looking for help in understanding what this error means and how I should try to eliminate it. Thanks!

Here is the dataframe with values for plotting, named "results_new_mean_gal":

```
GalCer(d18:0/16:0)  GalCer(d18:0/18:0)  GalCer(d18:0/20:0)  GalCer(d18:0/22:0)  GalCer(d18:1/12:0)  GalCer(d18:1/16:0)  GalCer(d18:1/18:0)  GalCer(d18:1/18:1)  GalCer(d18:1/20:0)  GalCer(d18:1/20:1)  ... GalCer(d18:1/26:0)  GalCer(d18:1/26:1)  GalCer(d18:2/18:0)  GalCer(d18:2/20:0)  GalCer(d18:2/24:0)  GalCer(d20:1/18:0)  GalSph(d18:1)-d5_287_Fragment   GalSph(d18:1)_282_Fragment  Donor   Time
0   0.215300    0.059700    0.070194    0.363689    0.0 14.116016   1.152977    

0.076444    1.755010    0.065237    ... 0.367733    0.397030    0.216907    
0.370995    2.363961    0.057962    0.0 54.771683   1945    0.0
1   0.231123    0.062481    0.077622    0.485070    0.0 10.033995   1.157515    
0.073333    0.368644    0.064531    ... 0.420362    0.239777    0.248076    
0.464601    2.715882    0.058266    0.0 54.953925   1945    24.0
2   0.201798    0.063592    0.102606    0.525483    0.0 15.053302   1.228159    
0.070733    1.183602    0.073261    ... 0.363202    0.411757    0.347854    
0.431674    2.998217    0.057020    0.0 54.579375   1945    168.0
3   0.328857    0.063406    0.095548    0.525920    0.0 13.270539   0.658445    
0.084318    1.276229    0.071935    ... 0.383221    0.236308    0.144282    
0.382030    3.332633    0.060944    0.0 54.716536   1945    336.0
4   0.217867    0.059378    0.077878    0.571903    0.0 12.489410   0.846313    
0.084687    1.693159    0.080074    ... 0.290250    0.300206    0.183519    
0.374895    2.723848    0.061060    0.0 54.521497   1945    672.0
```

And the following dataframe contains values for error bars, named "results_new_CV_gal":

```
GalCer(d18:0/16:0)  GalCer(d18:0/18:0)  GalCer(d18:0/20:0)  
GalCer(d18:0/22:0)  GalCer(d18:1/12:0)  GalCer(d18:1/16:0)  
GalCer(d18:1/18:0)  GalCer(d18:1/18:1)  GalCer(d18:1/20:0)  
GalCer(d18:1/20:1)  ... GalCer(d18:1/26:0)  GalCer(d18:1/26:1)  
GalCer(d18:2/18:0)  GalCer(d18:2/20:0)  GalCer(d18:2/24:0)  
GalCer(d20:1/18:0)  GalSph(d18:1)-d5_287_Fragment   
GalSph(d18:1)_282_Fragment  Donor   Time
0   0.334065    0.074880    0.027869    0.555201    NaN 0.005897    0.173130    

0.064572    1.156563    0.047950    ... 0.373245    0.266474    0.309391    
0.431493    0.340852    0.075503    NaN 0.005365    1945    0.0
1   0.079276    0.180951    0.083804    0.730536    NaN 0.082057    0.649561    

0.019622    0.327917    0.018683    ... 0.059414    0.340055    0.021224    
0.114184    0.192853    0.012973    NaN 0.004639    1945    24.0
2   0.137435    0.120870    0.414772    0.183564    NaN 0.103133    0.297932    

0.154821    0.116996    0.145507    ... 0.274355    0.311000    0.221077    
0.080608    0.117676    0.053936    NaN 0.000666    1945    168.0
3   0.388812    0.176556    0.263537    0.387674    NaN 0.208829    0.727563    

0.024587    1.096352    0.092637    ... 0.554185    0.430230    0.725164    
0.057672    0.027661    0.125046    NaN 0.000696    1945    336.0
4   0.140836    0.012758    0.230036    0.227757    NaN 0.068854    0.203473    

0.351434    0.436528    0.278715    ... 0.186993    0.041627    0.385178    
0.323510    0.099012    0.019424    NaN 0.000509    1945    672.0
```

Comment: what is .iplot?

Comment: @AndyHayden This is the inline plotting function from the plotly library. https://plot.ly/pandas/getting-started/

Comment: it monkey patches pandas GroupBy objects? wow.

Comment: Actually, it only works with DataFrame objects which is what I am passing to it in the loop by iterating over the GroupBy object.

Comment: When I had this problem with plotly, I used a debugger to find what might be the most frequent cause for this problem: One of the columns indicated for plotting occurs more than once in the dataframe.

On a sidenote: You never need groupby, instead you simply pass the grouping column as the desired channel (such as `color` or `facet_row`). Also, the easiest and preferred way to include data from another dataframe (e.g. for error pars) is to concatenate/join the data. In short: All plotting data goes into a single dataframe and each plot requires exactly one call to a plotly.express function.